# Multiple Fluid Images

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I have a simple container with an image in it.

```
<div class="container" style="width:800px;">
     <img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg">
</div>
```

If I set the img style `max-width: 100%;` the container can change width and scale the image inside it. Perfect.

However, what if I have a few images inside the container? like so.

```
<div class="container" style="width:800px; background:red;">
    <img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg">
</div>
```

The above code will not perform any scaling and overflow onto the next line - expanding the container height.

How can I make the images scale uniformly to fit a fixed width with pure CSS? Is it even possible?

Sandbox: http://tinkerbin.com/ijy5zgH3

Comment: If the number of images within the container is known, say 3 images, you can probably set `.container img {width: 33%;}`

Comment: @Neps That is the rub, the number of images is unknown. The only fixed value is the width of the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal but in that case, you can retain `img {max-width: 100%;}` but resort to a `<table>`

```
<table class="container" style="width:800px;">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This was my backup plan! Was hoping to find something more elegant. But we work with what we got! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you are willing to change HTML structure.

HTML:

```
<ul class="container" style="width:800px;">
    <li><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.lovehkfilm.com/panasia/aj6293/gu_gu_the_cat.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
img {max-width: 100%; }
li { display: table-cell; }
```

​
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XStVp/1/)

Comment: Thanks Gurpreet. This is also a fine solution. Was hoping to avoid table structures but it seems there is no other way. Thank you.